# Setting namespace and schema using java dom

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a root element in my output xml document that has no attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
..
</root>
```

I need it to look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="my.xsd">
....
</root>
```

I can't figure out how to do this correctly with the java DOM API.

Thanks!

Comment: ah, you beat me to the edit! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `NS` methods. In this case, the namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element root = doc.createElement("root");
root.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "my.xsd");
root.appendChild(doc.createElement("foo"));
doc.appendChild(root);
// see result
DOMImplementationLS dls = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();
System.out.println(dls.createLSSerializer().writeToString(doc));
```